# give him a $100 bill

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

How do you understand when bill is the money   or the statements of fees?
Of course if I am in a resturant and my friend tell me

> give him a $100 bill

I will give the money, but what if there is no data about the context?

How can I be more clear if I want to say give him 100$ paper money?

Comment: In a restaurant in the USA, you receive a check, not a bill for the cost of your meal.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, that's a bit nitpicky. Generally, people ask for the check at a restaurant, but it's by no means unheard of or at all incorrect to ask for the bill instead.

Comment: @Matt Not in the USA that I've grown up in. No one asks the waiter or server for "the bill," only "the check."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a native speaker of American English, I can say that in normal usage

A *hundred dollar bill* means the banknote.

A *bill of/for a hundred dollars* is a list of fees or charges.

Besides that, when is there ever "no data about the context"? Even if you say *I found a hundred dollar bill*, no one is going to think you are referring to a list of fees or charges.

Answer (score 1):

You would usually say:

> - Give him 100$ cash.

[Cash](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cash):

> - money in the form of coins or banknotes, especially that issued by a government.

Dictionary.com